# Passing string to PHP file to query SELECT statement

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to pass a string (ex. "name") to my PHP script which needs to get the "name" from the Android app by $_POST and then using that in a SELECT query and passing it back to the Android app.

I have everything made except I can only pass the string to the PHP script but I can't use it in the SELECT query. Here are my codes:

PHP code:

```
<?php
include "../dbc.php";
//include "get_id.php";

$value = $_POST["value"];
$response = array();

$q=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = :value");
$q->bindParam(':value', $value);
$q->execute();
while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $first_name=$row['first_name'];
    $last_name=$row['last_name'];
    $company_name=$row['company_name'];
    $loc=$row['loc'];
    $tel=$row['tel'];
    $website=$row['website'];
    $aboutme=$row['aboutme'];
    array_push($response, array("first_name"=>$first_name,"last_name"=>$last_name,"company_name"=>$company_name,"loc"=>$loc,"tel"=>$tel,"website"=>$website,"aboutme"=>$aboutme));
}

echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));
?>
```

Android code:

```
class GetUserSettings extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
    String json_get_settings_url;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        json_get_settings_url = "http://url.com/json.php";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... Voids) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(json_get_settings_url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING+"\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String JSON_STRING) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String value = settings.getString("user_name", "");
        //this is where it starts parsing the JSON from the URL
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("server_response");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                user_name = jsonChildNode.optString(value);
                et_user_name.setText(value);
                first_name = jsonChildNode.optString("first_name");
                et_first_name.setText(first_name);
                last_name = jsonChildNode.optString("last_name");
                et_last_name.setText(last_name);
                company_name = jsonChildNode.optString("company_name");
                et_company_name.setText(company_name);
                loc = jsonChildNode.optString("loc");
                et_loc.setText(loc);
                tel = jsonChildNode.optString("tel");
                et_tel.setText(tel);
                website = jsonChildNode.optString("website");
                et_website.setText(website);
                aboutme = jsonChildNode.optString("aboutme");
                et_aboutme.setText(aboutme);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something is wrong. Please restart the app or contact us.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

So from the code, as you can see, I am trying to pass the String "value" to my PHP code and then assign "value" to $value and then use $value in the SELECT query but I how can I pass the String "value" and then execute the query so I can use JSON to parse the data?

Comment: Your Android code is not posting anything to your php script. So the $_POST array is empty. Start adapting your php code to check if needed parameters/data comes in. And if not echo relevant info to the Android client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ContentValues() to pass a string to a php amd return the select query.

ContentValues values = new Content Values();
values.put("string",variable);

And you can pass url as

http://example.com/dir/page.php?var=variable

On php side

$var = $_GET['variable']:
 Now you can pass this $var in the select query.

Hope this helps.